# WooCommerce cart-shipping.php template - Radio button instead of select box

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, cart

I see in WooCommerce template default `cart-shipping.php`:

```
<select name="shipping_method[<?php echo $index; ?>]" data-index="<?php echo $index; ?>" id="shipping_method_<?php echo $index; ?>" class="shipping_method">
    <?php foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $method->id ); ?>" <?php selected( $method->id, $chosen_method ); ?>><?php echo wp_kses_post( wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) ); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

How can I change it from select box to radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, you don't have the right template version of `woocommmerce/cart/cart-shipping.php`, because I don't see your code, but this one (with already radio buttons).

So the reason could be that there is a customized old version of woocommerce templates in your theme. 
This is an excerpt of `cart-shipping.php` actual code (template version 2.5.0):

```
        <ul id="shipping_method">
            <?php foreach ( $available_methods as $method ) : ?>
                <li>
                    <?php
                        printf( '<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[%1$d]" data-index="%1$d" id="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s" value="%3$s" class="shipping_method" %4$s />
                            <label for="shipping_method_%1$d_%2$s">%5$s</label>',
                            $index, sanitize_title( $method->id ), esc_attr( $method->id ), checked( $method->id, $chosen_method, false ), wc_cart_totals_shipping_method_label( $method ) );
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', $method, $index );
                    ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

As you can see you have radio buttons by default.

You should update your theme (and WooCommerce plugin too).

References: [Github code source - woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/cart/cart-shipping.php)